# Create a RecyclerView(Grid Layout manger) inside a CardView

Tags: android

I am trying to make a custom favorites screen for my dialer app [image: this]

I can do the following:

- GridView inside a cardView enclosed by a recyclerview(with linearLayoutManager)
- Recycler view(with a gridLayoutManager) inside a cardView enclosed by a recyclerView(with LinearLayoutManager)

The card's height should be dynamic i.e change with the number of items.Also all items(photos) are clickable.
Can anyone tell me which approach is better?